# Issue in installing SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Before I have SQL Server 2005. It's gotten corrupted so I uninstalled and tried to installing a new one. While installing, the following error appears, but installed in Windows Authentication mode.

> *The SQL Server service failed to start. For more information, see the SQL Server Books Online topics, "How to: View SQL Server 2005 Setup Log Files" and "Starting SQL Server Manually.*

But when I tried to log in, the following error will appear:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.*
>
> *Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)*

Answer (score 1):

For your login issue check the following steps

1. Run SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Go to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS.
3. Make sure TCP/IP is enabled.

Check this link for detail.

http://support.webecs.com/KB/a375/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote.aspx

Comment: Thanks for Reply  But The issue is MMC could not create the snap-in might not have been installed correctly. Name:SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: ya i refered the site which is given by you

but the problem is 

SQL Server Network Configaration Manager(Local)
three Options should come that are
1.Sql Server Services
2.Sql Server Network Configaration
3.SQL Native Client 10.0 Configaration

for me these three are not comming that is the issue actually

Comment: http://egranthalaya.nic.in/How_to_Install_and_setup_SQL_Server_2005_Manually.pdf

in the above link Please see the step 21

SQl Server Database Services

only this option is not installing

Comment: can i Remove and Install New Operating System

Comment: check this link http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091103002329AA0koXS